# reading of csv into dictionary, first line becomes the name

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

in python
I have a csv file, which has lots of parameters in it like:

```
Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, email, etc
Adam1,Smith1,12 Connaugh Rd.,,adamsmith@gmail.com, etc...
Adam2,Smith2,12 Connaugh Rd.,,adamsmith@gmail.com, etc...
Adam3,Smith3,12 Connaugh Rd.,,adamsmith@gmail.com, etc...
```

How do I read it, so first line Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, email, etc
becomes the name of parameter in dictionary? So I can get

```
Dict{Name:Adam1,Adam2, Adam3
     Surname: Smith1,Smith2,Smith3
     Address1: 12 Connaugh Rd.,12 Connaugh Rd.,12 Connaugh Rd.
        etc.}
```

Since I'm going to use it in future, is that the best way to work with csv's or there is something better?

Update1:
ripr(row)
gives:

```
{None: ['\tSales Record Number', 'User Id', 'Buyer Full name', 'Buyer Phone Number', 'Buyer Email', 'Buyer Address 1', 'Buyer Address 2', 'Buyer Town/City', 'Buyer County', 'Buyer Postcode', 'Buyer Country', 'Item Number', 'Item Title', 'Custom Label', 'Quantity', 'Sale Price', 'Included VAT Rate', 'Postage and Packaging', 'Insurance', 'Cash on delivery fee', 'Total Price', 'Payment Method', 'Sale Date', 'Checkout Date', 'Paid on Date', 'Dispatch Date ', 'Invoice date', 'Invoice number', 'Feedback left', 'Feedback received', 'Notes to yourself', 'PayPal Transaction ID', 'Delivery Service', 'Cash on delivery option', 'Transaction ID', 'Order ID', 'Variation Details']}
{None: ['3528', 'steve33559', 'Steven sdf', '45678', 'sdfghj@dfgj.com', '1 sdfgh Road, ', '', 'dfgh', 'dfgh', 'ertyu', 'United Kingdom', '151216259484', 'Small stuff ', '', '1', '\xa311.99', '', '\xa30.00', '\xa30.00', '', '\xa311.99', 'PayPal', '21-Mar-14', '21-Mar-14', '21-Mar-14', '', '', '', 'Yes', '', '', '384858394n5838f48', 'Other 24 Hour Courier', '', '49503847573848', '', '']}
{None: ['3529', 'buyretry13', 'Tariq fhb', '345678', 'buyretry@uk.com', '80 rtyukfd Road', '', 'Manchester', 'wertyuk', 'M16 1KY', 'United Kingdom', '76543283858', 'Apple iPhone 5', '100329', '1', '\xa31.95', '', '\xa30.00', '\xa30.00', '', '\xa31.95', 'PayPal', '21-Mar-14', '21-Mar-14', '21-Mar-14', '', '', '', 'Yes', '', '', '45678723456', 'Royal Mail 2nd Class', '', '3456785737', '', '']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to transpose columns to rows, and apply that to a dictionary comprehension to extract the first element as the key:

```
import csv

with open(yourfile, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    result = {c[0]: c[1:] for c in zip(*reader)}
```

This produces one dictionary, each with all entries in a column as a list of values.

You'd be better of using [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) here however. This produces a dict object *per row*:

```
import csv

with open(yourfile, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

where `row` is then `{'Name': 'Adam1', 'Surname': 'Smith1', 'Address1': 'Connaugh rd.', ...}` for the first row, `{'Name': 'Adam2', 'Surname': 'Smith2', 'Address1': 'Connaugh rd.', ...}`, etc. The `DictReader()` object takes the keys from the first row in the CSV data.

This keeps each row of data together as one easy-to-access object instead of having to correlate your data between separate rows.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> sample = '''\
... Name,Surname,Address1,Address2,email,etc
... Adam1,Smith1,12 Connaugh Rd.,,adamsmith@gmail.com,etc...
... Adam2,Smith2,12 Connaugh Rd.,,adamsmith@gmail.com,etc...
... Adam3,Smith3,12 Connaugh Rd.,,adamsmith@gmail.com,etc...
... '''
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(sample.splitlines())
>>> print next(reader)
{'Surname': 'Smith1', 'Name': 'Adam1', 'Address1': '12 Connaugh Rd.', 'Address2': '', 'etc': 'etc...', 'email': 'adamsmith@gmail.com'}
>>> print next(reader)
{'Surname': 'Smith2', 'Name': 'Adam2', 'Address1': '12 Connaugh Rd.', 'Address2': '', 'etc': 'etc...', 'email': 'adamsmith@gmail.com'}
>>> print next(reader)
{'Surname': 'Smith3', 'Name': 'Adam3', 'Address1': '12 Connaugh Rd.', 'Address2': '', 'etc': 'etc...', 'email': 'adamsmith@gmail.com'}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, I get {None: at the beginning of each row, how do I get rid of them, or replace with something meaningful?

Comment: Can you show me the `repr(row)` output for a row? I am not certain what you mean.

Comment: I've updated the post, with repr(row) data, it was too big to insert it here

Comment: @ipsissimus: what code produced that? You have one key (`None`), and each row is the list value for that one key.

Comment: This was result of DictReader, the second code you provided

Comment: @ipsissimus: I must confess to being puzzled how you managed to get *that* result from `DictReader()`. Can you share a postbin or something of your actual file contents and the code you used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53991/discussion-between-ipsissimus-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Europe lost connectivity to Stack Exchange it appears. The iOS app using the API works but browser access fails right now. Also, out of time for tonight, sorry!

Comment: I would really appreciate your help later, since I'm stack with this trouble too, thanks a lot